# Get a list of lists for each group values without pivoting the table in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the follwing dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (4, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014])
df = df.stack().reset_index().drop(['level_0'], axis =1)
```

which gives me this table:

```
    level_1 0
0   2010    0.490534
1   2011    0.292247
2   2012    0.809696
3   2013    0.198586
4   2014    0.642714
5   2010    0.854330
6   2011    0.637989
7   2012    0.229752
8   2013    0.017705
9   2014    0.632559
10  2010    0.596599
11  2011    0.919915
12  2012    0.622230
13  2013    0.991401
14  2014    0.983660
15  2010    0.351667
16  2011    0.439194
17  2012    0.532181
18  2013    0.205366
19  2014    0.226996
```

I want to create a list of lists with each row but without pivoting the table first:

```
[[0.4905338749671617,
  0.29224663913303917,
  0.8096956093927243,
  0.19858573316125572,
  0.6427138499319793],
 [0.8543300469401851,
  0.637988503570788,
  0.22975189294097909,
  0.017704963198544643,
  0.6325592815879836],
 [0.5965991619700056,
  0.9199147665832661,
  0.6222296923842731,
  0.9914005292156067,
  0.9836596573737321],
 [0.35166657263076084,
  0.43919406028150476,
  0.5321807826469648,
  0.2053657224576596,
  0.22699615245608507]]
```

I know that if I pivot the table I can easily do it with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (4, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014])
data = df.values.tolist()
```

but would love to know if it is possible to do the same without pivoting the table first.

The expected output is:
[[first value of each year], [second value of each year], [third value of each year],...]

Comment: what is your expected output? Just the random values as list of lists?

Comment: Do you need just `data.tolist()` ? because that would give what you show.

Comment: Is the data sorted and without missing data points like you showed?

Comment: I need;
[[first value of each year], [second value of each year], [third value of each year],...]

Comment: Yes I wont have any missing data points

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data is correctly sorted/distributed, use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)/[`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) & [`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) :

```
cols = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]

data = df[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1, len(cols)).tolist()
```

Or, as suggested by *@mozway* :

```
data = df[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1, df["level_1"].nunique()).tolist()
```

Output :

```
# with np.random.seed(0)

[[0.5488135039273248,
  0.7151893663724195,
  0.6027633760716439,
  0.5448831829968969,
  0.4236547993389047],
 [0.6458941130666561,
  0.4375872112626925,
  0.8917730007820798,
  0.9636627605010293,
  0.3834415188257777],
 [0.7917250380826646,
  0.5288949197529045,
  0.5680445610939323,
  0.925596638292661,
  0.07103605819788694],
 [0.08712929970154071,
  0.02021839744032572,
  0.832619845547938,
  0.7781567509498505,
  0.8700121482468192]]
```

Comment: you could replace `len(cols)` by `df[0].nunique()`, of course this approach assumes the data is correctly sorted and without missing years

Comment: Thanks mozway, I included your suggestion in the answer ;)

Comment: It didnt give me a list of lists just one big list.

Comment: Ok but you don't mention that the first approach actually **works** ;). I fixed the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
[v.tolist() for v in df.set_index(0).groupby('level_1').groups.values()]
```

Comment: That groups the data by year , but I need :
[[first value of each year], [second value of each year], [third value of each year],...]